# Solve for x given formula for cubic interpolation

Tags: polynomials, interpolation, cubics

Given formula for a linear interpolation, I can solve for $x$ as follows:
\begin{align}
y = a(1-x)+bx\\
y = a+x(b-a)\\
x = \frac{y-a}{b-a}
\end{align}

How do I solve for $x$ given formula for cubic interpolation:
$$
y = a(1-x)^3 + 3bx(1-x)^2 + 3cx^2(1-x) + dx^3
$$

Comment: I would appreciate if someone could help me improve the question title  for better searchability for future readers

Comment: When you say you "derived" $x$, I assume you don't mean applying the derivative, as in calculus, right? You might want to consider using "solve for" instead of "derive".

Comment: @TheoBendit Thanks for the feedback I'll edit the question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find an analytical formula for $x$ here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Trigonometric_and_hyperbolic_solutions (however first you have to transform your cubic equation to the standard form $x^3+Bx^2+Cx+D=0$ and further continue by substitution $y=x-\frac{B}{3}$ to get the so-called depressed form $x^3+Ex+F=0$).

Or you can find $x$ numerically, by means of the Newton's method for example, which however gives you only one of the solutions.